# Nested routes URL path and params problems in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm simply trying to link to categories#new which is nested inside guides. I'm linking to it from the guides show page

```
 <%= link_to "Add new category", new_guide_category_path %>
```

Problem is that i get the error:

No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"categories", :id=>"blah"} missing required keys: [:guide_id]

It is using :id instead of :guide_id. How can i fix this so stores the param it uses :guide_id.

Or is there a different way to link to the guides/:guide_id/categories/new page and other nested resources pages

route:

```
resources :guides do
   resources :categories,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

Still learning rails so this might be a noob problem where you don't even use the path to link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you have model Guide and in your controller you got variable like

```
@guide = Guide.where(...)
```

In view you need to specify id of this model and simples way to do it just to pass this variable to url helper:

```
<%= link_to "Add new category", new_guide_category_path(@guide) %>
```

And this works with multiple nested resources too. For example:

route: `/foo/:foo_id/bar/:bar_id/buz/:id`

Just pass all these instance of models to helper like

```
show_buz_bar_foo_path(@foo, @bar, @buz)
```

And rails will get ids of this items by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
new_guide_category_path( @guide.id )
```

The `form_for` helper can get your nesting sorted in terms of submitting data but links to other paths are a different story.

Comment: Ah ok so the paths are mainly for forms. I get the error undefined local variable or method `guide_id' with `new_guide_category_path( guide_id )` so i guessing something like linking to @guide.categories.new might be the way?

Comment: Sorry, `guide_id` was a placeholder for however you're referencing the variable. If you're passing in the whole @guide then `@guide.id` should do it